# Can you use the Bloomberg API on Android?

Tags: java, android, bloomberg

I'm trying to write a simple program using the Bloomberg API on my Android phone. It works fine on my Desktop but when I try and port it over to the android app it won't even open a session. Does the API work on the phone?

PS I have a bloomberg subscription and I am connecting to the correct host, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You need to have the Bloomberg Terminal running on the machine where the API is being accessed and you're not allowed to send the information to another machine. This means that even if you stay logged in to a PC, and have that PC running a server application that takes requests from Android users and translates them into requests to the Bloomberg API - you're not complying with the Bloomberg Terminal license.

The above assumes that you're referring to the Desktop API.